# Each method not work for my rails appli

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't use the each method

```
@project.each do |project|
```

When I test in local this is good but when I test in my server this is not good the error is `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` I think is because my database is empty its correct ?

Comment: Always safe navigate for objects which can be nil.
Do `@project&.each do |project|`, In this case even if the `@project` is nil, it won't throw an error.

Comment: Check your code. The error means that `@project` is uninitialized. Without seeing the actual code and context, I can't offer any more help than that.

Comment: @AnuragAryan just hiding an error is not generally good. An error helps alert the programmer that they need to fix something.

Comment: @lurker I was under the impression that in OP's case, `@project` can be nil or empty. 
Thank you for the feedback though.

Comment: @AnuragAryan yes that is possible. Unclear from the OP's post exactly what they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have error in 

`@project.each do |project|
   code...
 end`

I thing that @project not have any data. you sure of send datas correct from controller.

Example in the controller 
`def index 
  @projects = Project.all
end`

in the view 
`@projects.each do |project|
   <h1><%= project.title%></h1>
 end`

Answer (score 0):

Because `@project` value is `nil`. `@project` value should be a collection. And you should name your collection variable as plural. ex: `@projects`

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have mentioned, your problem is that @project is an array on your local environment and nill on your server. It's very likely that's happening because you have added some records to your local db but not to your production one.

Still, you should rewrite your code to be able to handle not finding any project. If it were an ActiveRecord simple search then it should return an empty array which wouldn't cause trouble, so how are you getting this variable would be useful.